# How to remove Chinese brackets in r

Tags: r, data-cleaning

One of my table column looks as below, and my final goal is to extract the English diagnosis content from the raw content:

| Pre_dx |
| --- |
| 异位妊娠 Ectopic pregnancy （右侧输卵管峡部妊娠） |
| R22.002-头皮肿物 Mass of scalp |
| L90.500-皮肤瘢痕情况和纤维化 Scar conditions and fibrosis of skin |
| 1.腺样体肥大 Hypertrophy of adenoids |
| 2.鼻窦炎 Sinusitis |

The column data can be created as:

```
d3 <- data.frame(Pre_dx=c("异位妊娠 Ectopic pregnancy （右侧输卵管峡部妊娠） ","R22.002-头皮肿物 Mass of scalp","L90.500-皮肤瘢痕情况和纤维化 Scar conditions and fibrosis of skin","1.腺样体肥大 Hypertrophy of adenoids","2.鼻窦炎 Sinusitis"))
```

After I tried:

1. remove all the Chinese content
2. remove all the contents before "-"
3. remove all the contests before "."
   by using the code as below:

```
d3$PRE_eng=gsub("[\U4E00-\U9FFF\U3000-\U303F]", "", d3$Pre_dx)
d3$PRE_eng1=gsub(".*-", "", d3$PRE_eng)
d3$PRE_eng2=gsub("^.*\\.", "", d3$PRE_eng1)
```

I got the new table like this:

| Pre_dx | PRE_eng | PRE_eng1 | PRE_eng2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 异位妊娠 Ectopic pregnancy （右侧输卵管峡部妊娠） | Ectopic pregnancy （） | Ectopic pregnancy （） | Ectopic pregnancy （） |
| R22.002-头皮肿物 Mass of scalp | R22.002- Mass of scalp | Mass of scalp | Mass of scalp |
| L90.500-皮肤瘢痕情况和纤维化 Scar conditions and fibrosis of skin | L90.500- Scar conditions and fibrosis of skin | Scar conditions and fibrosis of skin | Scar conditions and fibrosis of skin |
| 1.腺样体肥大 Hypertrophy of adenoids | 1. Hypertrophy of adenoids | 1. Hypertrophy of adenoids | Hypertrophy of adenoids |
| 2.鼻窦炎 Sinusitis | 2. Sinusitis | 2. Sinusitis | Sinusitis |

I'd like to know how to remove the Chinese “（）” from "Ectopic pregnancy （）" in Row 1 of Column PRE_eng2.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the unicode ranges for `（` and `）` to your first `gsub` as well?

Comment: Can you provide data in a reproducible format using `dput` ? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Hi, I updated the column data in my question, let me know if it in the correct format that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your trial, you can remove Chinese brakets with

```r
gsub("\\（|\\）","",d3$PRE_eng2)
```

You can also combine them together with `|`

```
gsub("[\U4E00-\U9FFF\U3000-\U303F]|.*-|^.*\\.|\\（|\\）", "", d3$Pre_dx)
```